# Hide and clear selectInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I need to show\hide input and will be great get NULL or empty string if the input not exists, here reproducible example:

```
ui <- 
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = 'Test'),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      selectInput(
        inputId = 'mainInput',
        label = 'Main input',
        selected = 'Show',
        choices = c('Show', 'Hide')
      ),
      uiOutput(
        outputId = 'secondInputUI'
      ),
      actionButton(
        inputId = 'thirdInput',
        label = 'Check value'
      )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$mainInput, ignoreNULL = TRUE, {
    if (input$mainInput == 'Show')
      output$secondInputUI <- 
        renderUI(
          selectInput(
            inputId = 'secondInput',
            label = 'Second input',
            selected = 0,
            multiple = FALSE,
            choices = c(1, 0)
          )
        )
    else {
      output$secondInputUI <- 
        renderUI(
          selectInput(
            inputId = 'secondInput',
            label = 'Second input',
            selected = '',
            multiple = TRUE,
            choices = c(1, 0)
          )
        )
      # If uncommit - input value don't update and will return latest available before delete input
      # output$secondInputUI <- 
      #   NULL
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$thirdInput, {
    showNotification(
      session = session, 
      ui = paste(input$secondInput, collapse = ', '))
  })
}

shinyApp(
  ui = ui,
  server = server)
```

You can see commented part with setting NULL to uioutput, if it active - shiny return latest available value before clear that ui, so how to deal with that?

Comment: What do you want exactly, your question is not clear to me. If I select 'hide' and click 'check value' the output is empty. Do you want to hide the second input field?

Comment: The input returns nothing because he is empty and that because I commented part # output$secondInputUI <- NULL.
If uncomment that, the input will not be updated to an empty value and will be returned latest available value (except you clear input by hand before hiding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found another solution, the main idea is: update input value in observer for first input, hide second input from observer for the second input. Will be better if I show:

```
ui <- 
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = 'Test'),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      selectInput(
        inputId = 'mainInput',
        label = 'Main input',
        selected = 'Show',
        choices = c('Show', 'Hide')
      ),
      uiOutput(
        outputId = 'secondInputUI'
      ),
      actionButton(
        inputId = 'thirdInput',
        label = 'Check value'
      )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$mainInput, {
    if (input$mainInput == 'Show')
      output$secondInputUI <- 
        renderUI(
          selectInput(
            inputId = 'secondInput',
            label = 'Second input',
            selected = 0,
            multiple = FALSE,
            choices = c(1, 0)
          )
        )
    else {
      output$secondInputUI <- 
        renderUI(
          selectInput(
            inputId = 'secondInput',
            label = 'Second input',
            selected = '',
            multiple = TRUE,
            choices = c(1, 0)
          )
        )
    }
  })

  # THE TRICK HERE ####
  observeEvent(input$secondInput, ignoreNULL = FALSE, {
    if (input$mainInput != 'Show'){
      output$secondInputUI <-
        renderUI(NULL)
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$thirdInput, {
    showNotification(
      session = session, 
      ui = paste(input$secondInput, collapse = ', '))
  })
}

shinyApp(
  ui = ui,
  server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand. You could create a reactive variable that is independent of the UI, because inputs are not updated when the UI element is removed.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- 
  dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      title = 'Test'),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      selectInput(
        inputId = 'mainInput',
        label = 'Main input',
        selected = 'Show',
        choices = c('Show', 'Hide')
      ),
      uiOutput(
        outputId = 'secondInputUI'
      ),
      actionButton(
        inputId = 'thirdInput',
        label = 'Check value'
      )
    )
  )
server <- function(input, output, session){

  secondInputVar <- reactive({
    if(input$mainInput == 'Show'){
      input$secondInput
    } else {

    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$mainInput, ignoreNULL = TRUE, {
    if (input$mainInput == 'Show')
      output$secondInputUI <- 
        renderUI(
          selectInput(
            inputId = 'secondInput',
            label = 'Second input',
            selected = 0,
            multiple = FALSE,
            choices = c(1, 0)
          )
        )
    else {
      output$secondInputUI <- renderUI({
        NULL
      })
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$thirdInput, {
    showNotification(
      session = session, 
      ui = paste(secondInputVar(), collapse = ', '))
  })
}

shinyApp(
  ui = ui,
  server = server)
```